# How to forward DHCP A record registration to another domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp

I'm currently at work and we're having some troubles. We want to create a new domain for our area, but the DHCP server is not in our control. The DHCP server lists DNS as testdomain.com, however we want to make a new domain called testdomain1.com. We've been thinking of fowarding the DNS from testdomain.com to testdomain1.com so that way DHCP doesn't have to be changed. Basically

Client requests testdomain1.com
DHCP says DNS is at testdomain.com
testdomain.com tells client to go to testdomain1.com
client registers in AD at testdomain1.com and adds it's A record to DNS at testdomain1.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with standard software(Though I don't know much about windows server). However maybe it's possible for you to setup all the hosts in testdomain1.com as CNAME to corresponding hosts in testdomain.com.

Alternatively (though much more complicated), maybe you can periodically load the whole zone (you can use nslookup or dig for that once zone transfers is enabled on your DNS server), and make some script to process zone data and insert changed names in testzone1.com (and possibly remove those entries from testzone.com)

Answer (score 0):

That's... gonna be hard.  Windows Active Directory DNS does not handle forwarders that well. There are a TON of small records that are created in AD that can break with that setup.  I'd really try to get access to that DHCP server before I'd do a forwarder.